# $q.all for a promise returning boolean

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-resource

I am new to Angular JS. I am trying to use $q.all to call two `$resource` promises as shown below. The first promise returns a boolean and the second one returns a longer JSON object.

```
$q.all([one.get(arg1).$promise, two.get(arg2).$promise])
      .then(function(results){
            self.isAllowed = results[0].result;//undefined
            self.details = results[1].result; //correct JSON object
            });
```

How do I access the result from the first promise? `results[0]` only has  `$promise`, `$resolved`(which is set to true) and `_proto_` objects. It doesn't have the boolean returned by one's `$resource` call.

Also, I cannot make changes to the code to return something like `result: true` instead of just `true`.

Comment: `results[0]` should *be* the result that the promse fulfilled with, i.e. the boolean. That it is an object instead seems to suggest that you cannot make a resource that contains only a boolean. Can you show how you are consuming the resource normally, does it work there?

Comment: Previously I was using it by itself. `one.get({arg1}, function(success) { self.isAllowed= success}, function(err){...});`.

Comment: resources are always objects if your endpoint is not crud you should ot be using $resources but $http.